# Setting http.server in python3

Tags: http, python-3.5

I have setup a python server on server machine which is an aws instance and trying to access it using public_IP:80 from client machine which is in different network.
It is not able to load the data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple network blockers in this client/server communication.
One of those, which is highly probable is Security-group or NACLs in this AWS based communication.
If you are running your instance in EC2-Classic then you need to check security-group inbound rules for allowing client on port 80 and if it is running in AWS VPC then check the security-group inbound rules as well as Network ACLs for inbound as well as outbound rule.

In Security Group allow

> Type Http, Protocol TCP and source IP should your client IP or
>   0.0.0.0/0 (Less secure).

And in case of NACLs adjust it as below:

> INBOUND Rule:
>  100 HTTP (80) TCP (6) 80 
>   Allow 
>  OUTBOUND Rule:
>  100 Custom TCP Rule TCP (6) 1024-65535
>    ALLOW

Ephemeral port range can be adjusted here depending upon OS and distribution.

Apart from these adjustments you need to check if Firewall on client/server is blocking any such communication or not.